# How to get rid of this message: 'allow MiKTeX Package Manager to make changes to this computer'

Tags: packages, miktex

There is a popup for the MiKTeX package manager, which asks me about installing new package. But it is irritating, as it happens every time I compile? How to stop this.

I did the step: Refresh FNDB, but doesn't help.

-Sameer

Comment: What Sean says is true, this is not a MikTeX issue, but a "feature"  of windows from Winvista onwards called UAC (user access control). You can find how to disable it [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-user-account-control-uac-the-easy-way-on-windows-vista/).

Comment: Did it happens too if you use the non-admin version of the package manager?

Comment: Thanks for the comments..trying to follow what El has pointed to!

Answer (score 0):

I see that this was posted awhile ago, but I just today discovered another possible solution (I think). I clicked on the MiKTeX Options icon on the toolbar at the top of the screen and under the 'general' tab selected 'No' for 'Install missing packages on-the-fly.' I'm sure this will result in other issues later on, but it is working nicely for now.

Comment: I ran into issues with this 'solution' already and had to change the 'No' back to a 'Yes' but oddly enough, the original problem is still fixed. Any thoughts on this?